# Trying to get attendees set in google calendar API / PHP

Tags: php, ajax, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I´m trying to create an event and that part works, but it will not for some reason send out the invitations / attendees in the calendar system with google API using PHP. It does create the event but that also it. So I hope someone can help me figuring out what I´m doing wrong.

myfile.php
        // Event details

```
parameters = {  title: $("#event-title").val(), 

                event_time: {

                    start_time: $("#event-type").val() == 'FIXED-TIME' ? $("#event-start-time").val().replace(' ', 'T') + ':00' : null,

                    end_time: $("#event-type").val() == 'FIXED-TIME' ? $("#event-end-time").val().replace(' ', 'T') + ':00' : null,

                    event_date: $("#event-type").val() == 'ALL-DAY' ? $("#event-date").val() : null

                },
                'attendees': [
{'email': 'test@dds-slagelse.dk'},
],

                all_day: $("#event-type").val() == 'ALL-DAY' ? 1 : 0,

            };




$("#create-event").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',

    url: 'ajax.php',

    data: { event_details: parameters },

    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(response) {

        $("#create-event").removeAttr('disabled');

        alert('Event created with ID : ' + response.event_id);

    },

    error: function(response) {

        $("#create-event").removeAttr('disabled');

        alert(response.responseJSON.message);

    }

});
```

ajax.php file

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once('google-calendar-api.php');
error_log($_SESSION['access_token']);
try {
// Get event details
$event = $_POST['event_details'];
error_log(__LINE__);
$capi = new GoogleCalendarApi();
error_log(__LINE__);
// Get user calendar timezone
$user_timezone = $capi->GetUserCalendarTimezone($_SESSION['access_token']);
error_log(__LINE__);
// Create event on primary calendar
error_log($event['attendees0']);
$event_id = $capi->CreateCalendarEvent('primary', $event['title'], $event['all_day'], $event['event_time'], $event['attendees'], $user_timezone, $_SESSION['access_token']);
error_log(__LINE__);
echo json_encode([ 'event_id' => $event_id ]);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
error_log($e->getMessage());
header('Bad Request', true, 400);
echo json_encode(array( 'error' => 1, 'message' => $e->getMessage() ));
}
```

google-calendar.api.php

```
class GoogleCalendarApi

{

public function GetAccessToken($client_id, $redirect_uri, $client_secret, $code) {  

    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';            


    $curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_uri . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&code='. $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code';

    $ch = curl_init();      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);    

    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      

    if($http_code != 200) 

        throw new Exception('Error : Failed to receieve access token');



    return $data;

}



public function GetUserCalendarTimezone($access_token) {

    $url_settings = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/settings/timezone';

    $ch = curl_init();      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_settings);       

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token));   

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    

    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true); //echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      

    if($http_code != 200) 
        throw new Exception($http_code);



    return $data['value'];

}



public function GetCalendarsList($access_token) {

    $url_parameters = array();



    $url_parameters['fields'] = 'items(id,summary,timeZone)';

    $url_parameters['minAccessRole'] = 'owner';



    $url_calendars = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?'. http_build_query($url_parameters);



    $ch = curl_init();      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_calendars);      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token));   

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    

    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true); //echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      

    if($http_code != 200) 

        throw new Exception('Error : Failed to get calendars list');



    return $data['items'];

}


//'primary', $event['title'], $event['all_day'], $event['event_time'], $event['attendees'], $user_timezone, $_SESSION['access_token']
public function CreateCalendarEvent($calendar_id, $summary, $all_day, $event_time, $event_attendees, $event_timezone, $access_token) {

    $url_events = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events';



    $curlPost = array('summary' => $summary);

    if($all_day == 1) {

        $curlPost['start'] = array('date' => $event_time['event_date']);

        $curlPost['end'] = array('date' => $event_time['event_date']);

    }

    else {

        $curlPost['start'] = array('dateTime' => $event_time['start_time'], 'timeZone' => $event_timezone);

        $curlPost['end'] = array('dateTime' => $event_time['end_time'], 'timeZone' => $event_timezone);

    }

    $ch = curl_init();      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_events);     

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json')); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curlPost));   

    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      

    if($http_code != 200) 

        throw new Exception($http_code);



    return $data['id'];

}

}
```

I hope this make sense as I have tried so many attempts that I have lost track of it.

The Form Data that is send (after what i can figure out from google chrome is the following:

```
event_details[title]: Privat
event_details[event_time][start_time]: 2018-08-11T13:00:00
event_details[event_time][end_time]: 2018-08-11T15:30:00
event_details[event_time][event_date]: 
event_details[attendees][0][email]: test@dds-slagelse.dk
event_details[all_day]: 0
```

Comment: As far as I can see your CreateCalendatEvent method simply doesn't use the attendees data in the data it sends to Google. So the Google calendar never knows about them. The method accepts `$event_attendees` as a parameter but then doesn't use it. You need to add the data to your curl data in the format specified by google.

Comment: BTW any reason you're not using the PHP library provided by Google for talking their APIs? It gives you an OO interface to build the data structures you need, and then handles all the niceties of constructing the HTTP requests so you don't have to.

Comment: I could not get the PHP library from google to work after countless hours so once I got this to work (partly I know) I keept my focus here...

Answer (score 0):

ADyson, thanks for your help / hint. It was the missing curl that was the solution.

$curlPost['attendees'] = $event_attendees;

I hope it wont be to much of a bother, but it seems that it does not send out the invites for the events as hoped, even thought it does add the "guests" to the event.

The starting point for this solution is found here: http://usefulangle.com/post/29/google-calendar-api-create-event-php and if someone can please helt me to get *** "sendNotifications"=>true *** inserted or set correctly I would be very thankful. (would like to see how that parameter / function is set).

Best Regards
Jess

Answer (score 0):

This help to me:

$curlPost['attendees'] = [['email'=>$event_data['attendees']]];
$curlPost['sendUpdates'] = array("sendUpdates"=>"all");
$curlPost['reminders'] = array('useDefault' => true, 'overrides' => array('method' => 'email','minutes' => 20));